# How to save the content in p tag to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, html

I want to store the content inside the `<p>` tag into database. Is it possible?

```
<p align="center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCheckin" onclick="getLocation()">Check In</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCheckout" onclick="getLocation()">Check Out</button>
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }

</script>
```

Below is what I have tried. But I got error at the demo which is underlined by red.

```
protected void btnCheckin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Locate (Locate_LongLat) VALUES @Locate_LongLat";

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlconn);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Locate_LongLat", demo);

    sqlconn.Open();
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is it possible to store the content of p tag to the database? If cannot, how to store the longitude and latitude value?

Comment: You need to research how to get client side values back to the server. You might also tag what server technology you are using.

Comment: What is `demo` ?? You haven't defined any variable inside the method, nor is there a parameter on this method, that is called `demo` .....

Comment: Assuming you're using ASP.NET WebForms, why not just bind the longitude and latitude to two input fields and access them in the code behind file like this:  string longitude = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["longitude"]); and string latitude = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["latitude"]);  Then just insert them into the Db.